# huxtable footnote: how to set bold, italic etc. - html coding does not work

Tags: huxtable

If you set a caption: set_caption("...") html codes like "b, i, font size"  and so on are working

But with add_footnote("...") this isn`t true anymore, it just prints the html code as text

Does someone know how to fix this. Or how to style the footnote?

Comment: A reproducible small example would be great to help people hit the ground running when trying to help. Having said that, the footnote is added to the huxtable data so if you would like to adjust the entire footnote in the same way you could try using `set_bold()` or `set_italic()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `escape_contents()` on the footnote cell:

```r
library(huxtable)
jams |> 
   add_footnote("These jams are <i>tasty</i>") |>
   set_escape_contents(final(1), everywhere, FALSE) |>
   quick_html()
```

[image: HTML output]

You might also think about using markdown:

```r
jams |> 
   add_footnote("These jams are *tasty*", markdown = TRUE) |>
   quick_html()
```

which produces the same output but will also work in TeX and other formats.